# pandas define a season over which to calculate statistics

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm working with pandas dataframes that have time indices. I have several years of daily data, and I need to make some seasonal comparisons.

I know that I could use the `truncate` method to extract the periods and create new timeseries to work with, but I am wondering whether I can define a custom 'period' (e.g. 1st of May through 1st of Sept). Then I would like to calculate correlation coefficients between two different timeseries for only during that period. Is there a way to do this?

## some example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=4380, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4380, 4), index=rng)
```

### the problem:

I would like to calculate correlation coefficients on these times series (okay, for random data it doesn't make so much sense... but anyway) only for certain periods. That is, what is the correlation only during 'Spring', or 'Winter'? Where I can define Spring and Winter as custom periods? Basically, I just want to 'mask' the periods *outside* the seasons of interest.

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the months of the index by `df.index.month`, and then use [np.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to select what you want:

```
df[np.in1d(df.index.month, [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12])]
```